Connect Android Emulator to Windows COM Port to Send/ Receive data
I am developing a mobile app that will communicate with external devices through USB serial cable I have done this with physical device, but I want this with android emulator (Virtual mobile). I think if we can connect emulator USB port with laptops COM port we can do this communication.
So, what I am looking for is a way to communicate with virtual android emulator and USB serial device.

Have you seen: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator#other_new_features_and_enhancements USB passthrough is now available on Windows using -qemu -usb -device usb-host,vendorid=<usb-vendor-id>,productid=<usb-product-id>. (This should also have been workng on Linux and macOS already)

I am hearing this for the first time and i have tried as much I know. Can you explain this process. Thankyou in advance.
